# Melhorar a perfomance do python apply com lambda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Olá.

Estou desenvolvendo um código em python porém está demorando para rodar, gostaria de saber se existe algum outro método mais eficaz.

Abaixo segue a `def` que utilizo

```
def calcMovelMensalCircuito(nue,data,circuito):

    from datetime import datetime, timedelta

    days_to_subtract =365

    dias = timedelta(days=days_to_subtract)
    d=data-dias

    #print(dezembro.query("DATA<=@data & DATA>@d & CONJUNTO==@conjunto & CIRCUITO==@circuito & MUNICIPIO==@municipio & CLASSE==@classe & CAUSA==@causa & NUE_ORDEM==@nue"))
    return eventos.query("DATA<=@data & DATA>@d & NUE_ORDEM==@nue & CIRCUITO==@circuito")["DEC_EMPRESA"].sum()
```

Aqui utilizo o método `apply` junto com lambda, para criar um coluna com o valor:

```
dfCircuito['DEC_MOVEL']=dfCircuito.apply(lambda x:calcMovelMensalCircuito(x['NUE'],x['DATA'],x['DESCRICAO']),axis=1)
```

Comment: O que é este `eventos`? A demora não é devido ao fato de executar uma *query* para cada registro do seu dataframe?

Comment: Eventos é outro dataframe que contém os dados do banco dados, utilizo com base para os cálculos

Answer (score 0):

Erick, tudo bem?

Você pode substituir o query pelo método groupBy.

Execute esse código para verificar se realmente o que você queria foi alcançado.

`df[(df['DATA']<=data) & (df['DATA'] > d) & (df['NUE'] == nue) & (df['CIRCUITO'] == circuito)].groupby(['NUE','DATA','DESCRICAO'])['DEC_EMPRESA'].sum()`

Caso tiver sido o que você quer, basta agora colocar os valores em uma coluna:

`df[(df['DATA']<=data) & (df['DATA'] > d) & (df['NUE'] == nue) & (df['CIRCUITO'] == circuito)].groupby(['NUE','DATA','DESCRICAO'])['DEC_EMPRESA'].transform('sum')`

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

A `apply`  ai chama rsua função uma vez pra cada linha. O "lambda" aí não faz nada - é só um açucar sintático para passar as colunas específicas para a outra função  `calcMovelMensalCircuito` - seria trivial escrever isso sem o lambda, mas também não mudaria nada.

O que acontece ai, e você nao está contando na pergunta, é que essa função, `calcMovelMensalCircuito` faz uma query ao final - esse `query` é o que? 
Banco de dados? Algum serviço web? Não dá para adivinhar - 
Mas independente do que seja, é bastante claro que é aí que está a sua demora. 
Dá para assumir que essa query é uma chamada que faz I/O, seja pra um banco local, seja pra um serviço remoto - e o seu programa vai ficar parado aí esperando a resposta.

Como você esclareceu no comentário, no entanto, a query é de Pandas mesmo, feita completamente em memória - então estragégias de paralelização que envolvessem multi-threading, multiprocessing ou asyncio não iriam adiantar em nada.

O que acontece é que a "query" do Pandas é um negócio "força bruta" - ela percorre o dataframe onde é feita, linha a linha, e testa a condição todas as vezes - e gera um "dataframe virtual", que é basicamente uma marcação das linhas que interessam no dataframe original - e em cima desse ele faz o `sum`. E, no caso, ele está percorrendo *toda* a tabela de "eventos" para *cada* linha da tabela `dfCircuito` - isso faz o seu algoritmo ficar quadrático (O(M x N))

Mas, antes de a gente se profundar, não parece ser o caso,mas se fosse dos três parametros de entrada de `calcMovelMensalCircuito(nue,data,circuito)` (isso é, varias linhas fossem usar o mesmo valor), só colocar um cache na função `calcMovelMensal` resolveria - já que nos valores repetidos, com o cache, a chamada externa não seria feita.  Nesse caso seria só decorar a função:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def calcMovelMensalCircuito(nue,data,circuito):
    ...
```

Agora - como os valores de "nue" , faixa de datas, e circuito provavelmente são únicos pra cada linha, não tem nada muito "automático" a se fazer -só conecendo seu conjunto de dados -  mas uma alternativa seria usar particionamento dos dados que estão no dataframe "eventos"  - de forma que a query só rode num dataframe já reduido que tenha só os "circuito" iguais ao buscado.

Explico: se, por exemplo "eventos" tem mais ou menos 1 milhão de linhas, e uns 100 circuítos diferentes  -antes de fazer esse apply, você quebra programaticamente o "eventos" e cria 100 dataframes, de ~10.000 linhas cada em um dicionario `eventos_dict` -  a chave de cada dataframe, seria, claro, o "circuito" - 
Cada query de cada linha das suas originais então, teria que percorrer só essas  ~10000 linhas do cicuito certo, em vez do 1 milhão original.

Sem ser isso, teriamos que ver outras estratégias de indexar o dataframe de eventos - de forma equivalente a criação de um index em um banco de dados - mas eu não sei fazer o equivalente a isso no Pandas.